# null refference at acessing multiple object in xml wit c#

Tags: c#, xml, xna, xna-4.0

I'm trying to make a loader from xml to create menu. I have been having problem with the button. It always gives an error of null pointer.
Here is the code:
title.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<title>
  <background>Assets/background</background>
  <song>Assets/title</song>
  <button>
    <texture>Assets/background</texture>
    <position>10,10</position>
    <buttonaction>exit</buttonaction>
  </button>
</title>
```

xmlManager

```
static public class xmlManager
{
    static public titleData makeTitle(ContentManager content)
    {
        titleData title = new titleData();
        System.IO.Stream stream = TitleContainer.OpenStream("Content/title.xml");
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(stream);

        var titleXML = doc.Descendants("title").First();

        title.background = titleXML.Element("background").Value;
        title.song = titleXML.Element("song").Value;

        title.button = new List<Button>();
        title.button = (from button in doc.Element("title").Elements("button")
                            select new Button()
                            {
                                texture = button.Element("texture").Value,
                                position = StringToVector(button.Element("Position").Value),
                                buttonAction = button.Element("buttonAction").Value
                            }).ToList();
        return title;
    }

    static private Vector2 StringToVector(string str)
    {
        //convert a string to a point
        Vector2 vector;
        vector.X = Convert.ToInt32(str.Split(',')[0]);
        vector.Y = Convert.ToInt32(str.Split(',')[1]);
        return vector;
    }
}
```

It always stops inside the xml manager at the `select new button()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

XML element names are case sensitive. You have `buttonaction` in your XML, but `buttonAction` in your C# code.

I would also recommend using string casts instead of `.Value`, as `.Value` will produce a NullReferenceException if an element is not found, and these can be hard to track down:

```
select new Button()
{
    texture = (string)button.Element("texture"),
    position = StringToVector((string)button.Element("position")),
    buttonAction = (string)button.Element("buttonaction")
}
```

You would also need to modify your `StringToVector()` method to be able to handle null values. This will make your code more resilient against NullReferenceExceptions.

Comment: @PhilipHoseaChristianto Because Position is also lower case in the XML as `position` - fixed answer

Comment: i have change the buttonaction to buttonAction in the xml but it still didn't work. i also have add null exception on string to vector

Comment: You're probably getting that error because, as Chuck Savage pointed out, the capitalization of the name of your Position elements doesn't match the "position" string in your code.

Comment: i have embarrassed myself greatly TwT
thanks for the help sorry for the noob question